# OpenLayers 3 removeLayer failure?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I've been converting an OpenLayers 2 map application over to OpenLayers 3.
The map consists of two group layers (Base Maps and Overlays) that are defined within the Javascript code.   However, when the page loads (or autorefreshes), it reads from an XML file and loads layers of features into the map dynamically.

That part is all working fine.  What I'm having a problem with is the routine that, as a part of the page's auto-refresh feature, is supposed to remove all of the dynamically-added layers.

My original code:

```js
function erase_and_reload(){
  console.log("erase_and_reload has fired!");
  map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer){
   console.log("Existing layer that needs to be removed ?:");
   console.log(layer);
   
     var name = layer.get('name');
     var title = layer.get('title');
     console.log("layer name = " + name  + "   layer title = " + title);
          
     if (name){
      console.log("Found layer named = " + name);
      console.log("Removing layer named: " + name);
      map.removeLayer(layer);
     }
     
     
    });

// reload
 read_WW_xml();
}
```

(Yeah, I've got a log of console.log entries in here to try to figure things out.)

So, if I run this as-is... the log entry of "Existing layer that needs to be removed?" gets written 10 times, indicating to me that there are 10 layers.  When I look at the layer objects, I see the Base Maps one, the Overlays one, and a few others.  But certain other layers that actually do have "name" properties are completely missing.

But if I run this with the line "map.removeLayer(layer)" commented out, now that "Existing layer" line  gets written 17 times!   Seven more layer objects show up!

(FYI:  The phrase "title" is still in there because at first I thought the problem had something to do with the 'name' property, so I had temporarily tried matching off of the 'title' property instead..."if the title is not 'Base maps' or 'Overlays', then removeLayer.  But that behaved the exact same way.)

Even if .removeLayer is failing to remove the layer, I guess I'm not sure why this is all somehow aborting the loop for 7 iterations... to the point where it doesn't even write the first two console.logs ??

Thanks!

-= Dave =-

Comment: Have you try to use `map.getOverlays().clear();` and `map.getLayers().clear();`?

Comment: It looks like if I do "layer.getSource().clear();".... but bypass layers with the title of "Base maps" and "Overlays" (which therefore, bypasses their nested layers)... that seems to effectively erase the features from each layer for redrawing.    BUT, whether or not a given dynamically-fed layer will be needed with the next page refresh can change.  So, if I run this thing for a few days, there may be a buildup of unnecessary layers.  I wish the removeLayer would work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not actually abort those 7 iterations, it just skips those array items.

In your forEach cycle there is an array of references to map layers. If you take an element of that array (reference is "layer") and you remove it from map as it is, you remove the reference, so it is neither in the map nor in your array anymore and accidentally there is another reference on that index.

So if you have array:

0: layer0, name "layer0"

1: layer1, name "layer1"

2: layer2

after this forEach there will remain

0: layer1, name "layer1"

1: layer2

because after removal layer0, there is layer1 on the index 0 and AFTER that forEach moves along (to index 1), where it already finds layer without name.

To solve that, just use functions `getArray()` and `slice()` (to duplicate the reference array), something like that:

```
var refArray = map.getLayers().getArray().slice();
ref.forEach(function(layer)
{
  //your stuff
}
```

Comment: That appears to be working!  Thanks very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
function erase_and_reload(){
   map.getOverlays().clear();
   map.getLayers().clear();

   // reload
   read_WW_xml();
}
```

Comment: Well, I'd rather not waste resources redrawing the Base Map Layergroup and the Overlays Layergroup.   Those aren't going to change.

map.getLayers().clear() seems to wipe all layers... everything....